# How can I show my 2D arrayList using the <ui:repeat> in JSF

Tags: jsf, html-lists, uirepeat

I can show the objects of the plain arrayList.

ArrayList`<Object>`names;

```
<ui:repeat  value="#{bean.names}" var="t">
                          <ul>
                              <li  render="" id="hm">  

                                   <a>#{t.name}</a>
                             </li>
                          </ul></ui:repeat>
```

But if I have `List<ArrayList<Object>> names2  = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();`

I tried to use nested `<ui:repeat>` or `<c:forEach>` but it doesn't work. I dont want to use  data tables since I want to display them as a list.

E.g I tried to do this but it doesn't work, neither with `<ui:repeat>`, is it possible what I try to do?

```
 <ul>

                                        <li> 

                                              <c:forEach items="#{bean.names2}" var="row">
                                                <c:forEach items="#{row}" var="nested_row">

                                                    <c:forEach items="#{nested_row}" var="t">
                                                        <a>#{t.name}</a>
                                                    </c:forEach>

                                                </c:forEach>                                                
                                              </c:forEach>             

                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code attempt with *three* `<c:forEach>`s expects a 3D array/list. Get rid of that one `<c:forEach>` too much.

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.names2}" var="row">
    <c:forEach items="#{row}" var="nested_row">
        #{nested_row.name}
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

The same should work for `<ui:repeat>`.